# Automatically equal the size of the table

Tags: html, css

How do I maintain the tables at the same height even if contents of the other row are quite short, here is a picture for reference: 
[image]

those tables are taken from the database. And here is my code for the table:

```
<table width="" height="" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="1">
    <tr class="row_submit">
        <td height="150px" width="250px"><center><label>
            <input type="radio" name="payment" <?php if (isset($payment) && $payment=="$row[pay_name]") echo "checked";?>  value="<?php echo $row['pay_name']; ?>">
            <!--<img src="../paymentoptions/lbc.png" alt="LBC" class="picture" width="245px" style="margin:10px"/></label></td> -->
            <?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['pay_pic'] ).'"  height="150px"  width="150px" style="margin:10px"/>'; ?>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row_submit">
        <td height="80px" width="300px"><p id="pay"><?php echo $row['pay_desc']; ?><p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I tried adding height but I don't know why it won't work. It just makes the TD in the left pic bigger.

Help me fix their heights so it would always be equal.

Comment: don't use tables for layout... have a look into [**faux columns**](http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns)

Comment: `cellpadding`, `cellspacing`, `border`, `height` and `width` are deprecated as attributes on `table` etc. Use CSS instead. Also, if you are specifying the width as an attribute, omit the `px` part.

Comment: You have bad HTML structure, some tags haven't end tag (center, label, p). Check this for example http://jsfiddle.net/fauzi/c920qtsg/

Answer (score 1):

In the code, you have added height through inline style with different values.
Try assigning the height values equally for both `<td>`.
If you are trying with external css, you can not override the inline styles,
but u can use overriding operator in external styles, i.e `!` operator.

Ex:

```
td { 
    height: 100px !important; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must use tables then you can visually fudge this effect by having a parent table with two columns  each with a `border` attribute, and then your existing tables within each column with only the horizontal border set on the first row.

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/n2u97gjx/1/